# Android USB Tethering not working after upgrade

Tags: networking, usb

I have lost the ability to tether my phone (Android 5.0 Lollipop) via USB after installing Kubuntu 15.10. The computer doesn't detect the usb0 connection whereas in the Linux Mint OS (running on a different partition) it does.

```
victor@victor-laptop:~$ ls /sys/class/net
enp0s25  enxaa08117cff8c  lo  wlp32s0
```

I think that `enxaa08117cff8` is the USB connection but it keeps changing its name after every disconnection and the system doesn't connect to it automatically as in it would with Ethernet.

```
victor@victor-laptop:~$ ifconfig
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:26:3c:ba:3f  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2700000-f2720000 

enxaa08117cff8c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:08:11:7c:ff:8c  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8030 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8030 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:602738 (602.7 KB)  TX bytes:602738 (602.7 KB)

wlp32s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:6a:25:7a:60  
          inet addr:192.168.43.64  Bcast:192.168.43.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:6aff:fe25:7a60/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:45315 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13234 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:61843757 (61.8 MB)  TX bytes:1553306 (1.5 MB)
```